# How to turn NSManagedObject values into a Dictionary with key and value pairs?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, core-data

I have Core Data setup in my application so that when there is no internet connection the app will save data locally. Once a connection is established it will trigger online-mode and then I need to send that data that I have stored inside Core Data up to my database.

My question is how do you turn an entity into a dictionary such as this:

```
<Response: 0x1c0486860> (entity: AQ; id: 0xd000000000580000 <x-coredata://D6656875-7954-486F-8C35-9DBF3CC64E34/AQ/p22> ; data: {
amparexPin = 3196;
dateFull = "\"10/5/2018\"";
finalScore = 34;
hasTech = No;
intervention = Before;
responseValues = "(\n    31,\n    99,\n    82,\n    150,\n    123,\n    66,\n    103,\n    125,\n    0,\n    14\n)";
timeStamp = "\"12:47\"";
who = "Luke";
})
```

into this:

```
amparexPin: 5123
timeStamp: 10:30
hasTech: No
intervention: Before
```

Basically a dictionary, I am trying to perform the same operation on each set of data on each entity. I know it sounds overly complicated but its quite imperative that each entity go through the same filter/function to then send its data up to a database. Any help on this would be awesome!

Comment: `let stuff = Response as? [String: AnyObject]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to go here. The first is to have a protocol with some "encode" function, `toDictionary() -> [String, Any?]` that each managed object class implements in an extension and then call this function on each object before sending it.
The advantage of this way is that you get more precise control of each mapping between the entity and the dictionary, the disadvantage is that you need to implement it for each entity in your core data model.

The other way is to make use of [NSEntityDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription) and KVC to extract all values in one function. This class holds a dictionary of all attributes, `attributesByName` that could be used to extract all values using key-value coding. Depending on if you need to map the data type of the values as well you can get that from the NSAttributeDescription. (If you need to deal with relationships and more there is also `propertiesByName`).

A simplified example. (Written directly here so no guarantee it compiles)

```
static func convertToDictionary(object: NSManagedObject) -> [String, Any?] {
    let entity = object.entity
    let attributes = entity.attributesByName

    var result: [String: Any?]
    for key in attributes.keys {
        let value = object.valueForKey: key)
        result[key] = value
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
func objectAsDictionary(obj:YourObject) -> [String: String] {
    var object: [String: String] = [String: String]()

    object["amparexPin"] = "\(obj.amparexPin)"

    object["timeStamp"] = "\(obj.timeStamp)"

    object["hasTech"] =  "\(obj.hasTech)"

    object["intervention"] =  "\(obj.intervention)"


    return object
}
```